# `[MKMapView setRegion:]` method sets the map region to the opposite of the earth (in longitude) on iOS 15, but works well on iOS 14

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

#### How to produce?

1. Create Xcode  playground (iOS Map) in Xcode 13
2. Replace the original code with the code at the end
3. Run the code

**Expected to see:** The center of the map should be (latitude: 44, longitude: **-112**)

**But see:** The center of the map is (latitude: 44, longitude: **68**). The longitude is wrong.

Code piece:

```
//: A MapKit based Playground

import MapKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Now let's create a MKMapView
let mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:1160, height:282))

// Define a region for our map view
var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()

mapRegion.center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44, -112)
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 80
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 360

mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

// Add the created mapView to our Playground Live View
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Temp fix

The following is a temp fix.

Based on some research and testing, I found that:

Suppose `regionToSet` is the region you are going to set to the map view.

1. get the fitted region `fittedRegion` from the region to set to the map view `regionToSet` through `[MKMapView regionThatFits:]` method.
2. If the `fittedRegion.span.longitudeDelta` equals 360, and `fittedRegion.span.latitudeDelta` is greater than **twice of** the final shown region’s `span.longitudeDelta`, the final shown region will have an opposite center in longitude compared with `regionToSet`.

This is strange, and I have sarched the web but found no official material. As a temp fix, I override the `[MKMapView setRegion:animated:]` method, and it fixes the issue on my side. Attach the piece of the code:

```
- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKCoordinateRegion fittedRegion = [self regionThatFits:region];
    if (@available(iOS 15, *) && fabs(fittedRegion.span.longitudeDelta - LNG_DEGREES) < CGFLOAT_EPSILON) {
        fittedRegion.span.longitudeDelta -= 1;
        fittedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0;
        [super setRegion:fittedRegion animated:animated];
    } else {
        [super setRegion:region animated:animated];
    }
}
```

Explaination about the temp fix:

1. `fittedRegion.span.longitudeDelta -= 1;` Although we change the longitude span from 360 to 359, the final region will not be changed. Because the maximum longitude span shown by the MKMapView is 180. Both of 360 and 359 longitude span will be scaled to 180.
2. `fittedRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0;` When the final region has 180 longitude span, the latitude span will be calculated automatically according to the map view's width/height aspect ratio, and is not influenced by the latitude span you set to it. But the issue can be fixed this way.